Counter example: if each function of a composite function being not differentiable at a point, then the composite function is also not differentiable
I was reading counter example in calculus book. And stuck one problem:

If a function $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=a$ a and a function
$f(x)$ is not differentiable at $g(a)$, then the function $F(x)=f(g(x))$ is not
differentiable at $x=a$
Answer: Let $f(x)=2x+|x|$ and $g(x)=\frac23x-\frac13|x|$. Because $g(x)$ not differentiable at $x=0$, and $f(x)$ isn't differentiable at $g(0)=0$. But $F(x)=x$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

I didn't find the motivation how did the author manage to get those function. Initially, I was thinking to construct two such function which is inverse to each other but not differentiable at $x=a$ and $g(a)$. I was also thinking to take absolute value functions but couldn't get how to construct them.
Is there any insight which can help to get them? Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Can you think of a discontinuous function that might be "repaired" into something continuous when composed with the absolute value function?

The way in which the author presented the counter-example is somewhat obscuring the key idea. Note that those functions are the same as: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x, &x\geq 0 \x,&x<0\end{cases}\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{3}x, &x\geq 0 \ x, & x<0\end{cases}.$$ Can you now see why it works?

He used precisely your idea 'to construct two such function which is inverse to each other but not differentiable at $x=a$
and $g(a)$'!

Right now, I couldn't think of any discontinuous function which might be "repaired" into something continuous when composed with the absolute value function. @user3716267 Can you give a hint?

@falamiw Consider any function that takes only values {-1, 1} (a modified step function will do).  When composed with the absolute value function in the correct order, this becomes a constant function (certainly differentiable).

The absolute value approach absolutely can work.
Note that if $\operatorname{im}(f) = \{-1, 1\}$, then $h(x) = (\operatorname{abs} \circ f)(x) = 1$, which is clearly differentiable.
So, a step function that transitions from -1 to 1 will work.  In fact, we can take a function that is nowhere-continuous or nowhere-differentiable (think: Thomae's function) and still "recover" a differentiable function by composition with the absolute value.

I think the question was how the author would naturally arrive at the given example, not to construct new examples.

Ah, Thank you very much. @user3716267.  Simple and nice solution.

@Lieven the question had two parts; i answered the second.

The creative part is the realization that two real functions with kinks in their graphs can be each other's inverses. Then note that the graphs of inverses are mirror images with respect to the first diagonal. So it is sufficient to take any invertible function with a kink in its graph.
The most obvious example of a nondifferentiable real function is $|x|$ but it is not invertible; nor is $|x|+x,$ so the next simplest example is $|x|+2x.$
The calculation part is then to determine the inverse of that. If you prefer algebra you can solve the equation $|x|+2x=y$ for $x;$ if you prefer geometry you draw the graph of $y=|x|+2x$ and notice that it consists of the left hand side of the graph of $y=x$ and the right hand side of the graph of $y=3x.$ The mirror image has the graph of $y=x$ left and the graph of $y=x/3$ right. To convert back to algebra, take the average of those two ($y=2x/3$) and add the missing part to match left and right, which is $y=\pm x/3.$
